# append to dataframe in function - is globalenv really required

Tags: r

I am using the following code, which works fine (improvement suggestions very much welcome):

```
WeeklySlopes <- function(Year, Week){

  DynamicQuery <- paste('select DayOfYear, Week, Year, Close from SourceData where year =', Year, 'and week =', Week, 'order by DayOfYear')
  SubData = sqldf(DynamicQuery)
  SubData$X <- as.numeric(rownames(SubData))
  lmfit <- lm(Close ~ X, data = SubData)
  lmfit <- tidy(lmfit)
  Slope <- as.numeric(sqldf("select estimate from lmfit where term = 'X'"))
  e <- globalenv()
  e$WeeklySlopesDf[nrow(e$WeeklySlopesDf) + 1,] = c(Year,Week, Slope)
}

WeeklySlopesDf <- data.frame(Year = integer(), Week = integer(), Slope = double())
WeeklySlopes(2017, 15)
WeeklySlopes(2017, 14)
head(WeeklySlopesDf)
```

Is there really no other way to append a row to my existing dataframe. I seem to need to access the globalenv. On the other hand, why can sqldf 'see' the 'global' dataframe SourceData?

Comment: Normally in R one passes objects via the arguments and returns the result as the return value of the function. e.g. `addCol <- function(data, name, col) { data[[name]] <- col; data }`

Comment: Thanks. Yes that's what I would think. Other languages also allow you to pass as reference. Can you please adapt my code as I get errors for WeeklySlopesDf[[Week]] <- Week etc. ... Still it does not explain how sqldf can 'see' the 'global' dataframe SourceData

Comment: are you looking for the `<<-` operator?  ?`<<-`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dfrm <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=letters[1:10])  # reproducible example

myfunc <- function(new_a=20){ g <- globalenv(); g$dfrm[3,1] <- new_a; cat(dfrm[3,1])}
myfunc()
20
dfrm
    a b
1   1 a
2   2 b
3  20 c  # so your strategy might work, although it's unconventional.
```

Now try to extend dataframe outside a function:

```
dfrm[11, ] <- c(a=20,b="c")
```

An occult disaster (conversion of numeric column to character):

```
str(dfrm)
'data.frame':   11 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: chr  "1" "2" "20" "4" ...
 $ b: Factor w/ 10 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

So use a list to avoid occult coercion:

```
dfrm <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=letters[1:10]) # start over
dfrm[11, ] <- list(a=20,b="c")
str(dfrm)
'data.frame':   11 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ b: Factor w/ 10 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

Now try within a function:

```
myfunc <- function(new_a=20, new_b="ZZ"){ g <- globalenv(); g$dfrm[nrow(dfrm)+1, ] <- list(a=new_a,b=new_b)}
myfunc()
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "ZZ") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

str(dfrm)
'data.frame':   12 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ b: Factor w/ 10 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

So it succeeds, but if there are any factor columns, non-existent levels will get turned into NA values (with a warning). You method of using named access to objects in the global environment is rather unconventional but there is a set of tested methods that you might want to examine. Look at `?R6`. Other options are `<<-` and `assign` which allows one to specify the environment in which the assignment is to occur.